# rails scope and joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have tried everything i thought would work for this and am turning up nothing.

in rails 3, I need to find all users with a cd player in their car. A car has one user and one radio, and a user belongs to a car, and a radio has many cars.

I am stumbling on how I would perform this search via a scope in the user model.

```
class User  
  belongs_to :car

class Car  
  belongs_to radio
  has_one :user, :dependent => destroy

class Radio  
  has_many :cars
```

Comment: You should tell what your database schema looks like if you wish to get help.

Comment: _"a user belongs to a car, and a radio has many cars"_ this is a weird model. Can you show some code?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean this:
Car has `radio_id`, User has `car_id`,
since a radio has many cars and car has one user. The table with the foreign key always is on the belongs_to end of the relationship.

Without really knowing the structure you're looking for, something like the following should work:

```rb
scope :with_cd_player, joins(:cars).where('cars.radio_id is not null')
```

if there is a category column on the radio, the following would work.

```rb
scope :with_cd_player, joins(:car => :radio).where('cars.radio_id is not null').where("radios.category = 'cd_player'")
```

For Rails Version >= 4:

```rb
scope :with_cd_player, -> { joins(:cars).where.not(cars: { radio_id: nil }) }
```

Comment: Since Rails 4, scope bodies need to be callable, so it's:

`scope :with_cd_player, -> { joins(:cars).where('cars.radio_id is not null') }`

Answer (score 14):

Also you can use `merge`:

```rb
Author.joins(:books).merge(Book.available)
```

Source: https://gorails.com/blog/activerecord-merge