# Active Record Filter on Two Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am building a reservation system where users can search for an open reservation. Reservation has an :on scope that filters the reservations that are booked on a given day and time. This filter on Reservations alone works fine, but I also want to add a filter to the Table model for a given `seating_capacity` (guests) so I can display all of the booked reservations that match a given `seating_capacity` on a given day/time. Any ideas how to add that filter?

Models

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :table, optional: true

  scope :on, -> (day, time) { where('date = ? AND starts_at <= ? AND ends_at > ?', day, time, time)}
end

class Table < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :users, through: :reservations

  def self.free_on(guests, day, time)
    reserved_table_ids = Reservation.on(day, time).pluck('DISTINCT table_id')
    reserved_table_ids ? where.not(id: reserved_table_ids) : all
  end

  def self.reserved_on(guests, day, time)
    reserved_table_ids = Reservation.on(day, time).pluck('DISTINCT table_id')
    where(id: reserved_table_ids)
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class TablesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @reserved_tables = Table.reserved_on(params[:guests], params[:day], params[:time])
    @open_tables = Table.free_on(params[:guests], params[:day], params[:time])
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_tag(tables_path, :method => "get", id: "table-search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :day, params[:day], class:"datepicker", placeholder: "Select Day" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :time, params[:time], class:"timepicker", placeholder: "Select Time" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Schema

```
  create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "table_id"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.time     "starts_at"
    t.time     "ends_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["table_id"], name: "index_reservations_on_table_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_reservations_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "tables", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "seating_capacity"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end
```

Comment: What problem do you have with the way you have approached it? It would be easier to know what is the specific problem.

Comment: I can filter the reservations based on the `:date` and `:starts_at` and `:ends_at` times. But I want to add a scope that filters the tables based on their `:seating_capacity` and chain that to the reservation :on filter. This way I will get only the tables that are >= `seating_capacity` at a chosen date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the seating_capacity scope using `joins(:table)` , this is how it looks:

```
scope :with, -> (capacity) { joins(:table).where(tables: {seating_capacity: capacity}) }
```

Then you can query specific reservations for day, time and seating_capacity like this:

```
Reservations.on(day, time).with(capacity)
```

Comment: In this query the `:with` scope returns all the `Reservation` with the exact `capacity`, but you can do the same for greater `seating_capacity` as well. It depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I tried that but tables are still not filtering on `seating_capacity`. When the query contains `(seating_capacity >= '4')`, all tables are returned including those with a seating capacity of 2.

Comment: That's because the syntax used is incorrect. Try this one: `joins(:tables).where("tables.seating_capacity >= ?", capacity)`

Comment: `:tables` won't join on `Reservation` because of the `belongs_to` relationship. `:table` will join, but I get a `PG::SyntaxError` at `(table.seating_capacity)`. I can't call `seating_capacity` on it...

Comment: you are completely correct, I misread the db:schema ! try to use `joins(:table)` and `("tables.seating_capacity >= ?", capacity)`.  tables - plural inside the `where()`. I'm fairly sure this should work. In case it does, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Datagrid is good gem to add filters easily on pages.

https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid

checkout demo: http://datagrid.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join good example is given here

[rails scope and joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622959/rails-scope-and-joins)

Answer (score 0):

```
@reservationsWithinInterval1 = Reservation.where('startdate >= ? AND startdate < ? , @reservation.startdate, @reservation.enddate)

@reservationsWithinInterval2 = Reservation.where('enddate >= ? AND enddate < ?, @reservation.startdate, @reservation.enddate)
```

Then check if

```
  if @reservationsWithinInterval1.count > 0 || @reservationsWithinInterval2.count>0
  flash[:notice] = 'Select different time. Car already reserved in this time'
```